# Insertar imagen en correo php

Tags: imagen, html-correo

estoy intentando introducir una imagen en un correo, no para que sea como adjunto, sino para se vea en el correo cuando se abra.
Este es el enlace que pongo.

[image]
https://privada.mgsehijos.es/preproduccion/img/cana.jpg

con su etiqueta `img src=""` correspondiente.

Pero cuando abro el correo de gmail, no aparece la imagen, aparece un icono de imagen y cuando le doy a inspeccionar sale esto:

https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/6MU7OPngwcG8QzrblEvJ5HMz9J73OXG6BgbCUQLmgYcg0RQVrdZZ2BiW8qdULTzvrm2KA4u1myED4dr15_yIaxDEw2CS3GbG2WdGJ-c=s0-d-e1-ft#https://privada.mgsehijos.es/preproduccion/img/cana.jpg

Comment: Si cargas la imagen https://privada.mgsehijos.es/preproduccion/img/cana.jpg en un navegador dice que hay un error de configuración en la seguridad de la página y no permite cargarla directamente, puede que sera la razón por la que gmail la bloquea.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a centrarme en solucionar ese problema.